# What actually happens when a pointer to integer is cast to a pointer to char?

Tags: c, casting

```
int i=40;
char *p;
p=(char *)&i;//What actually happens here?
printf("%d",*p);
```

What will be the output? Please help!

Answer (score 7):

```
p=(char *)&i;//What actually happens here?
```

It takes the address of `i` and casts it to a `char` pointer. So the value of `*p` is now the first byte of `i`. What that value is, is platform dependent.

Comment: Most likely that would be either 0 or 40 (depending on endianness of the machine).

Comment: Why is cast needed , what is the difference between `char *p = (char *) &i ` and `char *p = &i `?

Answer (score 6):

Let's start by looking at how the contents of `i` and `p` would be laid out in memory (assuming big-endian order):

```
Item               Address               0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----               -------               ----------------------
   i               0x08000000            0x00  0x00  0x00  0x28
   p               0x08000004            0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

Since `p` is being declared as an auto variable, it's not initialized to anything and contains a random bit pattern represented by `0x??`.

In the line

```
p = (char *)&i;
```

the expression `&i` evaluates to the address of `i`, or 0x08000000, and its type is `pointer to int`, or `int *`.  The cast converts the type from `int *` to `char *`, and the result is assigned to `p`.

Here's how things look in memory after the assignment:

```
Item               Address               0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----               -------               ----------------------
   i               0x08000000            0x00  0x00  0x00  0x28
   p               0x08000004            0x08  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

So the value of `p` is now the *address* of `i`.  In the line

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

the type of the expression `*p` is `char`, and its value is whatever is stored in address 0x08000000, which in this particular case is 0.  Since `printf` is a variadic function, the value of `*p` is promoted from type `char` to type `int`.

So for this particular case, the ouput is "0".  If the order were little-endian, the map would look like

```
Item               Address               0x03  0x02  0x01  0x00
----               -------               ----------------------
   i               0x08000000            0x00  0x00  0x00  0x28
   p               0x08000004            0x08  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

and the output would be "40".

Note that this whole example assumes that integer and character pointers have the same size and layout; that's not guaranteed to be true everywhere (see the [Online C Standard (n1256 draft)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 6.2.5, paragraph 27), so you can't rely on this working everywhere the way you expect (assuming I'm correct in thinking that `int` and `char` are not compatible types as defined by the standard, but I could be wrong on that).  Type punning in general is not safe.

Comment: Your description assumes that `int*` and `char*` pointers have the same size and layout, but the visible behavior of the program doesn't.  The C Standard guarantees that any object can be accessed as an array of characters, so the OP's code will access the first (lowest-addressed) byte of `i`.  The value of that byte, as others have pointed out, depends on the implementation.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why is cast needed , what is the difference between `char *p = (char *) &i ` and `char *p = &i `?

Comment: Why is cast needed , what is the difference between `char *p = (char *) &i ` and `char *p = &i `?

Comment: @SurajJain: The difference is that `char *p = (char *) &i;`islegal, and `char *p = &i;`is not. There is no implicit conversion between `char*` and `int*` (though some compilers might allow it, preferably with a warning). Pointer conversions can be dangerous, letting you treat an object of one type as  if it were of another type, so the language requires such conversions to be explicit.

Comment: @KeithThompson If the compiler allows it with a waring , like "initialisation from incompatible type " then are they same , do they behave same. This is bugging me from a long time.

Comment: @SurajJain: Early versions of C were more lax about implicit conversions. The rules were tightened up by the 1989 ANSI standard, but many compilers permit such conversions to avoid breaking old code. `char *p = &i;` is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. That diagnostic (unfortunately, IMHO) can be a non-fatal warning. It's not clear whether the behavior is defined or not. You need to take warnings seriously; treat them as fatal errors unless you're sure that your code is right and the compiler is wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson   Ok , Sir , can you check this question , i asked this long back , i have answered it when things were clear to me , i just want to make sure that i do not misead anyone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826036/confused-about-pointer-derefere

Answer (score 2):

here you are

`int i = 40;` //allocating memory for integer i and assigning value 40 to it

```
char *p = (char*)&i;
```

so here you are defining a pointer variable and assigning it the address of i after casting it to `char*`

suppose `i` is allocated at `1021 address` so p will have that address with the limit of 1 byte so it should hold  `first 8 bit from the representation of 40;`

as 40 has been cover under first 8 bit of 2 byte it will hold a char equivalend of 40 but as you are printing it with `%d` it shopuld print `40`;

Comment: Except that the machine might be big endian in which case, you'll get 0.

Comment: Why is cast needed , what is the difference between `char *p = (char *) &i ` and `char *p = &i `?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  On Windows, the output will be 40, but this is just because of a lot of coincidences:

First of all, printf does not (cannot) check the type of its arguments, so since it sees %d in the format string, it assumes that the given argument is an int.  Although *p is only a char, the result is promoted to an int (as is for every argument that is not specified in the function prototype).

Second, p will point to the memory taken by the variable i, but since it's a char pointer, it will only take one byte from the memory of i.  Since Windows/Intel uses Least-Significant-Byte first convention, 40 will be stored as byte pattern "40 0 0 0" so, since *p takes the first byte (char), the result will be 40.  If i would have the value 256 or bigger, the result would be incorrect.

Comment: Also See This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826036/confused-about-pointer-dereferencing

Answer (score 1):

[What happens when int pointer is typecasted to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114740/what-happens-when-int-pointer-is-typecasted-to-char)
There is another question marked duplicated to here, I try to explain for it.

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    char *x;
    x = (char *) &a;
    a=512;
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc a.c && ./a.out
513
```

Why it is 513? We can use gdb to see the root cause.

```
$ gcc a.c -g && gdb ./a.out
(gdb) list
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3        int main(){
4            int a;
5            char *x;
6            x = (char *) &a;
7            a=512;
8            x[0]=1;
9            x[1]=2;
10           printf("%d\n",a);
```

set a break point at line 8 of a.c, and run

```
(gdb) b a.c:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40113d: file a.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
```

once program stop at break point, print variable a's memory address.

```
(gdb) p &a
$2 = (int *) 0x7fffffffd9d4
(gdb) p x
$3 = 0x7fffffffd9d4 ""
```

variable a's memory address is 0x7fffffffd9d4, and variable x's value is the same.

before show memory content, let's understand how 512 in hex format, it is:

```
00 00 02 00
```

and x86 is little endian, so in memory it should be:

```
[higher address] 00 02 00 00 [lower address]
```

let's show the real memory, just as same as we thought.

```
(gdb) x/4xb 0x7fffffffd9d4
0x7fffffffd9d4: 0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00
```

then, show memory address of x[0] and x[1], and convert the memory content to real value, it should not difficult to understand why print out 513.

```
(gdb) p &x[0]
$4 = 0x7fffffffd9d4 ""
(gdb) p &x[1]
$5 = 0x7fffffffd9d5 "\002"
```